# Looking for a good terminology for permutations having no substring

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-groups

What is the good name for permutations of [1,...,n+1] having no substring [k,k+1]
http://oeis.org/A000255 ?

Comment: Stepless? Impatient? :D

Comment: Stepless is what i tried :) But somehow it has uncomfortable negation "having step"

Comment: I'd use "stepful" instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These permutations are called "plus irreducible".

See http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212163v1.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much. Great reference! This permutations are important for me, i hoped for shorter  name, but this name is conceptual.

Comment: Let me remark that much more is now known about the topics that are covered in that preprint. A starting point is Vatter's recent survey article [http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.5159](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.5159)

Comment: Oh many thanks Michael! I have arrived to this alien for me combinatorics from computations in characteristic classes and will be very happy to learn